# Where does Leiningen install the clojure libraries?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Runnig lein for the first time, it installs clojure, but were to?
It does not seem to be in
/Library ...
~/Library ...
~/.lein ...

Is there an established location for clojure.jar and the contribution jars on Unix/OS X## Heading ##?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leiningen uses maven (or, to be more precise, the underlying libs which implement maven), which by default will install all dependencies under `$HOME/.m2/`.

Answer (score 3):

The default path is given by

```
(.getPath (clojure.java.io/file (System/getProperty "user.home") ".m2" "repository")))
```

as used by [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate/blob/master/src/main/clojure/cemerick/pomegranate/aether.clj#L29).